# Why the dnscrypt site does not work?

Tags: ssl, dns, privacy, crypt

https://download.dnscrypt.org/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-resolvers.csv not available. 
Before dnscrypt.org redirects to https://dnsprivacy.org, now it redirect to https://www.opennic.org.
Whats happened? Can I use opennic servers in dnscypt?

Answer (score 0):

The project has a new home: https://dnscrypt.info

And you can absolutely use many OpenNIC servers via this protocol. There is even a dedicated list.